# Variable from Navigationcontroller to navigation.phtml

Tags: php, controller, zend-framework2

I am new Zend2.
The question how can i pass some var or array to my navigation.phtml, i succeeded with layout. I want to controle it from my NavigationController

What am i missing?!

Navigationcontroller:

```
namespace Front\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

class IndexController extends AbstractActionController {

function __construct() {
        return $this->layout()->myVariable = 'navigation Test';
    }
}
```

navigation.phtml:

```
<?php print_r($this->layout()->myVariable); ?>
```

module.config

```
'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'Front\Controller\Index' => 'Front\Controller\IndexController',
        'Front\Controller\Pages' => 'Front\Controller\PagesController',
        'Front\Controller\Navigation' => 'Front\Controller\NavigationController'
    ),
),


    'template_map' => array(
        'layout/layout'     => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
        'meta'            => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/meta.phtml',
        'navigation'            => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/navigation.phtml',
```

Answer (score 0):

You use your controller somewhat wrong. As I'm not willing to teach basics, please simply refer to [the official manual](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user-guide/forms-and-actions.html) and see the section [Forms and Actions](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user-guide/forms-and-actions.html) as well as [`Zend\View` QuickStart](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.view.quick-start.html)

All in all, the biggest suggestion i can give you: don't use a framework if you're not willing to work yourself through the Documentation...

Answer (score 0):

First, don't return anything in your constructor.
Next, Assuming you have a default route to navigation.phtml, you define a function in the controller

```
public function indexAction {

    $foo = 'hello';
    $bar = 'mum';

    return new ViewModel(array(
    'variable1'    => $foo,
    'variable2'    => $bar));
}
```

Then you can use variable1 and variable2 as javascript vars like this:

```
var var1 =<?php echo $this->variable1; ?>;
var var2 =<?php echo $this->variable2; ?>;
```

Or you can use the values directly in html:

```
<label><?php echo $this->variable2; ?></label>
```